# Jquery Validation Plugin not working in Jquery ui custom dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using validate.js library given on this link http://jzaefferer.github.io/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js to validate the text fields of pop-up form made using Jquery custom dialog box.

Whenever i click in the submit button,i keep getting the error"validate not defined"..I can't understand whats wrong with my code..

I want the plugin to validate all the fields given in the pop-up form...

Please Help..

Code..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Dialog - Animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type= text/javascript>
$(function() {
$( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  width:800,
  height:800,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }

});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#dialog").validate();
});

function isNumberKey(evt){  <!--Function to accept only numeric values-->
    //var e = evt || window.event;
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
     if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
&& (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
    return true;
}   
    </script>
    <style>
     textarea { 
     vertical-align: top; 
      }
     </style>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="dia">
      <form name="dialog" method="get" action="">

     <div id="dialog1" title="Upload Details">
     <fieldset>
     <legend><p>Please fill in the follwing Item details to compalete the uploading process.</p></legend><br><br>

     Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" id="cIname"   name="Iname"size="30" placeholder="Item Name"/><br><br>

     <p><div id='ccontactform_category_errorloc' class='err'></div>

 <label for="ccategory"  style="margin-bottom: 90px;margin-top:50px">Category: </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <select id="ccategory" name="category"class="input">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">
     [Choose Category]
     </option>
     <option value="Arts and entertainment">Arts and entertainment</option>
     <option value="Automotive">Automotive</option>
     <option value="Business">Business</option>
     <option value="Computers">Computers</option>
     <option value="Games">Games</option>
     <option value="Health">Health</option>
     <option value="Internet">Internet</option>
     <option value="News and Media">News and Media</option>
     <option value="Recreation">Recreation</option>
     <option value="Reference">Reference</option>
     <option value="Shopping">Shopping</option>
     <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
     <option value="World">World</option>
     </select>
     <div id="choose_own_text"></div>
     </p><br>

     Brand:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="cIbrand" name="Ibrand" size="30" placeholder="Item Brand"/><br><br>

     Price (Rs):&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="text" name="price" id="cprice"size="20" placeholder="Enter Price" maxlength="15" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/> .00 ps<br><br>

    <label for="cIdescrp"  style="margin-bottom: 90px;margin-top:50px">Description:</label>
   <textarea rows="15" cols="40" id="cIdescrp" name="Idescrp"style="resize: none;overflow:auto" onkeypress=""></textarea><br><br>

    Mobile No:&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="text" name="Num" id="cNum"size="20" placeholder="Enter Valid Number" maxlength="10" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/> <br><br>




   <button id="Submit" onclick="validate()">Submit Details</button>

   </fieldset>
    </div>

    </form>
     <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>

    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Quote OP:**

> *I keep getting the error "validate not defined".*

It sounds like you have not properly included the Validate plugin script:

```
<script src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"> </script>
```

Instead of linking directly to the Github file, use the CDN link [provided by the developer](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for this purpose:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js

Also include `type="text/javascript"` to make it valid HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

---

And of course, your jQuery selector target, `$("#dialog")`, is incorrect.  The hash, `#`, is trying to target an `id` which does not exist.

Either add `id="dialog"` to your `form` tag...

```
<form id="dialog" name="dialog" method="get" action="">
```

OR change your selector to target the element by its `name` attribute...

```
$('[name="dialog"]').validate();
```

---

Your code:

```
<button id="Submit" onclick="validate()">Submit Details</button>
```

Do not use inline JavaScript.  With jQuery, inline JavaScript is ugly and obsolete.  In this case, there is no practical needs to call `.validate()` again.   It's the *initialization* for the plugin and only needs to be called once on DOM ready; you've already done that.

Use this:

```
<button id="Submit">Submit Details</button>
```

---

See demo below for how to declare rules.  In demo, I used your code and applied `required` to the first field.  Fields are identified by `name` attribute.  To make a `select` list `required`, the first `option` item **must** contain `value=""`.

**Working DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/aqJVm/

---

I strongly suggest that you thoroughly review the documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Tried the changes you recommended.As you can see in the code posted in the question i have already included type="text/javascript".Do i need to add it somewhere else?? Even after making the above edits like changing the url of the js file and making <form id="dialog"...>,the the text fields are still not getting validated.I'm not getting an error but I'm not getting any output either..Please suggest furthur course of action...

Comment: Also i haven't added any custom error messagees and their CSS properties if the required fields are not filled.Do i need to add them or they are added automatically by the plugin???

Comment: @Lucy, you very clearly do **not** have `type= text/javascript` within your `<script>` tags for `jquery`, `jquery-ui`, or `jquery-validate`.  See my edited answer.

Comment: I have added type=""text/javascript" in my code and then I tried validating the other input fields using the same technique as the 1st field but it's not working as seen in this link http://jsfiddle.net/aqJVm/1/ .I have another query, will your fiddle code work in a pop-up form showed in the code I pasted in the question because I am tring to implement this in a pop-up form by embedding the code in jquery using jquery ui.I am using ur technique in my code but not being able to get any output..any idea why??